# Merge 3 physical monitors into one virtual monitor on Gnome

Tags: linux, multiple-monitors, gnome, xrandr, xinerama

I have 3 1080p monitors. I am Using Manjaro GNOME, but I would use Ubuntu if that's the only solution. I would like to combine them into a single display, à la eyefinity/xinerama. I understand I can use `xrandr --setmonitor VirtualMonitor auto Phys1,Phys2,Phys3` to do this. And indeed, `xrandr --listmonitors` shows VirtualMonitor with the desired dimensions. However the behavior of the GNOME WM behavior doesn't change. It still snaps to the corners of each screen.

I'm not actually sure what I *should* be seeing. I gathered from [here](https://gitlab.gnome.org/GNOME/gnome-desktop/-/issues/123) that it at least works on openbox, but I haven't confirmed it works in my case.

Ideally I would like for the GNOME DE to retain it's behavior of 3 separate screens, but for games to launch in 5760x1080. How can I accomplish this, and ideally test that it iss working on a LiveUSB.

Comment: Did you find a solution for this? I'm currently struggling with this same issue.